# Browser Push notifications for Microsoft Edge server side

Tags: microsoft-edge, web-push

From what I read, Microsoft Edge still does not support Web Push (it is still under development, as per [site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/pushapi/) ). So what is the best way to implement browser push notification for Microsoft Edge?

The link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/device/web-notifications-api - explains how we can send from a Javascript. But am trying to understand how I can send a notification from a different server side component (Java), to Microsoft Edge browser? Do we get any tokens like how we get when we use FCM in Chrome? Can someone provide me pointers on this? The application running on Microsoft Edge will be an angular 4 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Javascript Fetch API, AJAX, Long Polling, WebSockets or SSE. Once you get the notification on the client side you can use vanilla Javascript and the Notification API to display the notification.